# Why qt does not read a file

Tags: c++, qt, file

I have the following lines of code:

```
QFile file("1.txt");
qDebug() << file.readAll();
```

The file is locating in project directory. When I compile the code, I get:

> "QIODevice::read (QFile, "1.txt"): device not open"

Comment: First try to print out the process *current working directory*, I'll bet anything that it isn't what you expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must open the file before reading.

As a starting point (from the documentation):

```
QFile file("in.txt");
if (!file.open(QIODevice::ReadOnly | QIODevice::Text))
    return;

while (!file.atEnd()) {
    QByteArray line = file.readLine();
    process_line(line);
}
```

Other options can be found [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qfile.html#reading-files-directly).